# asymptotical expansion for $u_{n+1} = \arctan u_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I am trying to get an asymptotic expansion of the following sequence:
$u_0 = 1$ and $u_{n+1} = \arctan u_n$. Here is what I tried:

First I noticed that $u_n \rightarrow 0$, and a limited expansion with Cesaro theorem gave me $u_n ^{-2} \sim \frac{2n}{3}$, i.e. $u_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{3}{2n}}$

I am trying to push the asymptotic expansion further:
$u_{n+1}^{-2} - u_n^{-2} = \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{15}u_n^2 + o(u_n^2)$.
Therefore, with a telescopic sum :
$u_n^{-2} - u_0^{-2} = \frac{2n}{3} - \frac{1}{15} \sum{u_k^2} + \sum{o(u_k^2)}$.
Since $u_k^2 \sim \frac{3}{2n}$, the comparison relations summation theorem gives us :
$\sum{u_k^2} \sim \frac{3}{2}\sum{\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{3}{2}\sum{\frac{1}{k}} + o(\sum{\frac{1}{k}}) = \frac{3}{2}\ln n + o(\ln n)$ (Am I right until here?)

The same argument gives $\sum{o(u_k^2)} = o(\ln n)$.

So $u_n^{-2} = \frac{2n}{3} - \frac{1}{10}\ln n + o(\ln n)$.

Another limited expansion finally gives:
$u_n = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2n}} + \frac{3}{40}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\ln n }{n\sqrt{n}} + o\left(\frac{\ln{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)$.

Is this asymptotic expansion right?

Thank you very much for your help,

AF

Comment: just a reference, not an answer: the general case of iterative sequences where the function has a power series $x-a_kx^k + \cdots$ for $k>1$ and $a_k >0$ is treated in de Bruijn, *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis* chapter 8. Your leading term is definitely right.  These two [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518011/for-u-n1-frac12-arctanu-n-why-u-n-sim-2-nu-0-sqrt1-frac89u-02?rq=1) [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246828/asymptotic-expansion-of-u-n-1-frac12-arctanu-n?rq=1) are closely related to your question.

Comment: $u_n^{-2} =\color{red}{1}+ \frac{2n}{3} - \frac{1}{10}\ln n + o(\ln n)$ would be better

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes but $1 = o(ln(n))$